# Boolean simpliication problem

Tags: boolean-algebra

Question

[image]

My answer
[image]

[image]
 I stuck in the middle. How to simplify it further

Comment: How simple do you expect the final expression to be ?

Comment: Please type your question using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It does not simplify much further.

Comment: Not much more to say: in general, the four monomials are there to stay. However, you are halfway through showing that $(x\oplus y)\oplus z=x\oplus(y\oplus z)$

Comment: The next to the last equation has four terms giving the disjunctive normal form.

Comment: Wow, bad question. Other than the spelling mistake ('fint'), the question is already assuming that $\oplus$ is associative, but that is of course something that has yet to be shown.